# Working with many to many relationship in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I am currently working on a "practice" project with Rails 4 on many to many relationships. It is really one of the few things that I do not really know how to do with rails. Currently, I have two models-a physicians and a patients model. I have tied them together with an appointments model. Here is my code that I have so far: (I will only include the physicians and appoints code since I am not currently working with the patients model.)

Physicians model code:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :appointments
    has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end
```

Appointments model Code:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :physician 
    belongs_to :patient
end
```

Physicians Controller:

```
class PhysiciansController < ApplicationController

 def index 
    @physicians = Physician.all 
 end 
end
```

Appointments Controller:

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController

def index 
    @appointments = Appointment.all
    @physicians = Physician.all 
 end 
end
```

The Appointments index page code-where I want to show the doctors for each appointment:

```
<h1>Showing Appointments</h1>

    <% @appointments.each do |appointment| %>

        <% appointment.physicians.each do |physician| %>

            <h3><%= appointment.physicians.name %></h3>

        <% end %>

    <% end %>
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "appointments", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.integer  "physician_id"
      t.integer  "patient_id"
      t.datetime "appointment_date"
      t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  end

  create_table "patients", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string   "name"
      t.datetime "created_at", null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "physicians", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string   "name"
      t.datetime "created_at", null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

If needed my routes:

```
  resources :patients
  resources :physicians
  resources :appointments
```

Yes, I do not have a lot of code. I am not using a scaffold and building everything myself. (It is how I feel I learn the best.) The specific error that I am getting is the following: undefined method `physicians' for #<Appointment:0x007fa7d5bf7370> as well as undefined method`each' for # if I change take away the s in the following line-since it will not match the physicians variable in the controller:

<% appointment.physician.each do |physician| %> (This shows each error message which I can easily solve.)

Now again, I am learning how to work with multiple databases. I can get the physician id to appear no problem. However, I want to go into the physicians db and pull out the name based on the physicians id. (Hopefully that makes sense.) Any help will be appreciated! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both `Physician` and `Patient` `belong_to` `Appointment`, it is a one-to-many association. Because of this, you need to refer to the association as singular:

```
appointment.physician # not physicians
appointment.patient # not patients
```

Your view should look like this:

```
<h1>Showing Appointments</h1>
<% @appointments.each do |appointment| %>
    <h3><%= appointment.physician.name %></h3>
<% end %>
```

All that said, it seems your associations are off. `belongs_to` associations imply that the associated model can only belong to one model. Meaning, your current setup would imply that a `Physician` and `Patient` could only belong to one `Appointment` which is almost certainly not the case. I think `has_one` seems more appropriate in this case:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :physician 
  has_one :patient
end
```

And the rest remains the same!

Comment: Where should I make this change?

Comment: See my edit. Your view needs to be fixed. Also, you likely don't need `@physicians = Physician.all` in your appointments controller since you can retrieve the physician through the appointment

Comment: Although I don't think this is the right approach. Does a Patient really belong to an appointment? Belongs_to implies that both the `Physician` and `Patient` can't be associated to other `Appointments`. For this reason, I think your `belongs_to` associations should be `has_one`

Comment: Brennan-your solution worked!! I am just playing around with this app to learn more about how to structure everything! Thank you for the help!

Comment: Look at my last comment as well. I'm glad it works, but I still think it could be improved with better associations. Editing my answer to include that Good luck!